# How to connect these different smart home devices?

Tags: google-home, ikea-tradfri, xiaomi-mi, bridge

Somehow I ended up with a mix of smart home devices. What hub/bridge/connector device should I use to connect the ones below?

My devices:

1. Google Home
2. Google Home - Mini
3. Xiaomi (Mijia) Gateway v.2 EU-Version
4. Osram smart socket
5. Ikea TRÅDFRI remote

     +
6. Arduino
7. Raspberry Pi

---

Can be a device from my list, an app or something else.

EDIT: **What I want to achieve**: Most importantly I would like to control the `Osram smart socket` (turn it on/off) through the `Ikea TRÅDFRI` remote and/or the `Xiaomi (Mijia) Gateway`.

Comment: You need to explain what you actually want to achieve here, just saying "connect" doesn't actually help.

Comment: @hardillb Thanks for pointing that out, added it. Most importantly I would like to control (turn it on/off) the `Osram smart socket` through the `Ikea TRÅDFRI` remote and/or the `Xiaomi (Mijia) Gateway`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [zigbee2mqtt](https://github.com/Koenkk/zigbee2mqtt) project. It supports a ton of zigbee [devices](https://www.zigbee2mqtt.io/information/supported_devices.html) including your remote and socket, as far as I can tell.

However, you need an CC2531 USB Stick, which acts as zigbee gateway, plugged into a computer (a Raspberry Pi will do).

Control of the devices is via MQTT as the name implies.

Nice side-effect: now you can add any kind of supported devices, freely mixing and matching different brands.